# tsql to update highest value when new highest value occurs otherwise retain last highest value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to update the `highvaluesegment` when new higher current value segment occurs else retain the `lasthighestvalue` attained.

In given day when currentvalue decreases

for eg: `4 to 2` then `Highestsegmentvalue = 4` and `currentvaluesegment = 2`

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database. Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546). Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server, you can use the window functions

**Example**

```
Select DateKey
      ,CurrentSegmentRank
      ,highestValueSegment = max(CurrentSegmentRank) over (Order By DateKey)
 From  YourTable
 Order By DateKey
```